# Browsers don't warn that Adobe Flash Player is not installed

Tags: jquery, adobe, flash

I've a computer with Windows Server 2003 without Adobe Flash Player in which Firefox (v3.6) and Safari coundn't play a video and the user wasn't warned about the missing plug in.

Is this a known issue? In that case is there any solution as web programmer (not as user)?

In case this is not a known issue or even if it is not suppous to happen, is there any way to know if the user has Adobe Flash Player installed to warn him in case not? (I'm using jQuery if that helps).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this jQuery plugin : http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqplugin.

Usage (if the plugin /mimetype is enabled the properties returns true, otherwise returns false):

```
jQuery.browser.flash //Flash
jQuery.browser.sl //Silverlight
jQuery.browser.pdf //PDF format
jQuery.browser.java //Java
jQuery.browser.qtime //Quicktime
jQuery.browser.wmp //Windows Media Player
jQuery.browser.shk //Shockwave
jQuery.browser.rp //Realplayer
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser cannot inform the user by design. It does not know if a component is essential. See "graceful degradation" and "progressive enhancement" (google). You have to use Javascript to detect missing plugins and decide if you want to tell the user or just show alternative content. Google this: http://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=detect+flash&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: In my understand browsers do know if a component is essential. In fact, I've just tried uninstalling Adobe Flash Player in my pc (Windows seven) and FF v3.6 warned me also Chrome and IE did.

Comment: No they don't (know if it's vital), how could they? For example, many sites use a small Flash component for uploads or for cross-domain requests. If there is no flash, that component is not essential - the site simply reverts to using (less comfortable) HTML uploads. What some (most? all?) browsers do is if the component occupies visible space it displays some sort of "missing plugin" message, yes. That I should have mentioned (now you did).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery plugin that will detect flash, prompt user to download it, etc:
http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/

It is your responsibility as the developer to tell the user when he needs flash, not the browser's