# How to check if there is macromedia flash player installed on browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify, flash

I am using uploadify plugin to upload images. On some browsers uploadify button is not shown because of unavailability of macromedia flash player, I guess.

Is there any way to check if there is macromedia flash player installed, If not then show a link to download flash player at the place of upload button.

Thanks

Comment: Check this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171088/browsers-dont-warn-that-adobe-flash-player-is-not-installed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

```
var hasFlash = false;
try {
  var fo = new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash');
  if(fo) hasFlash = true;
}catch(e){
  if(navigator.mimeTypes ["application/x-shockwave-flash"] != undefined) hasFlash = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) plugin for Flash detection. The [tutorial is here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/swfobject.html)